# How to select based on unnormalized column

Tags: sql, postgresql

firstly sorry for vague title  wasn't sure how to explain it. Loooking at the query below I want to pull incidents out where 'truck1' attended. Not just on its own but when other vehicles attended with it.  Im sure its something straight forward but can't work it out.

```
select
i.incident_number
Vehicles,
countofvehicles

FROM

(


SELECT


i.Incident_Number,
array_agg(ir.RESOURCE) as vehicle,
count(ir.RESOURCE) as countofvehicles



FROM INCIDENT as i
JOIN RESOURCE as ir on i.Incident_Number = ir.Incident_Number 

--WHERE ir.  like '%Truck1%'

GROUP BY i.Incident_Number) i
```

Result

```
incident_Number       vehicle               countofvehicle
     1             car1,car2,bike1                 3
     2             car1,car2,truck1                3
     3             truck1                          1
     4             car1                            1
```

If I wanted to see where only the incidents truck1 attended, using WHERE ir.RESOURCE like '%truck1% would only bring back incident number 3 and not incident 2 where it attended with other vehicles.  How can I get around this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this, just a `having` clause:

```
SELECT i.Incident_Number,
       array_agg(ir.RESOURCE) as vehicle,
       count(ir.RESOURCE) as countofvehicles
FROM INCIDENT i JOIN
     RESOURCE ir 
     ON i.Incident_Number = ir.Incident_Number 
GROUP BY i.Incident_Number
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ir.RESOURCE like '%truck1% THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1;
```

In fact, you probably don't need the `join` either, because the only field you are taking from `INCIDENT` is also in `RESOURCE`:

```
SELECT ir.Incident_Number,
       array_agg(ir.RESOURCE) as vehicle,
       count(ir.RESOURCE) as countofvehicles
FROM RESOURCE ir 
GROUP BY ir.Incident_Number
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ir.RESOURCE like '%truck1% THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1;
```